# Android Custom ListView Text Color

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, colors

I am trying to change text color of my Listview.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
 android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, stg1);
```

I have used default XML to call list of data and now the requirement is to change text-color of this list-view. I know I can do with other custom classes but is there any other way that I can change text-color by using this class only.

I have searched lot and tried so many other solution but every one is suggesting to use custom class, but I don't want to use custom class.

Below is link which I have referred.

[How to change the list view text color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11794052/how-to-change-the-list-view-text-color)

[Android: Change text color in ListView for singleChoice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14191685/android-change-text-color-in-listview-for-singlechoice)

[how to change the color of the text of the default ListView in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11734005/how-to-change-the-color-of-the-text-of-the-default-listview-in-android)

[Android ListView Text Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533440/android-listview-text-color)

[Change ListView's textcolor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564789/change-listviews-textcolor)

[How to Change List View Text color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095757/how-to-change-list-view-text-color)

Ans so many other link also but every one is suggesting to use custom class, take text-view and change the color of text-view but I don't want to use any other XML file or any custom class.

Even I don't know this is possible or not so please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a custom class? It gives you more flexibility.. using a custom class, this can be done in just a few lines of code..

Comment: I know, but i am loading data from database inside this list-view and this is the very easiest way to load data from database with simple check box with multiple check.

Comment: There will be no difference between this and a custom class.. in terms of loading data from database and having multiple checkboxes..

Comment: @AmulyaKhare, i tried with custom classes to load data from database inside listview with multiple checkbox but i did not get success. If you have any working example then please suggest or give a link. That will be a great help.

Comment: Also do you want to change the color of text box depending on position or change all of them to some particular color (say all text now in red)?

Comment: Change all with same color not depending on position or any other thing...

Comment: Then the answer is simpler.. just try my answer first and let me know. I will post in a bit

Comment: But if i use custom adapter class then i am not able to get all data in list-view. That's why i have used this. If you have any working code, example or any link then please suggest me that will be a big help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Step 1)**: Create an XML layout file `custom_list_item_multiple_choice`:

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
/>
```

Where, `android:textColor="#FF0000"` specifies your text color.

**Step 2)**:  Init the adapter like this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
 R.layout.custom_list_item_multiple_choice, stg1);
```

everything else remains the same.. everything should work fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot... One more question if i want to change text based on position then how can i do that.

Comment: Then you definitely need a custom class that extends `ArrayAdapter`. You simply override the `getView()` method. Thats all. Rest everything remains the same..

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But i don't know how to use this custom class. can you give example please.

Comment: This is probably not the right place to post an example, but you could take a look at these similar answers that I have posted. Thats exactly what you need to do: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19657563/827110, http://stackoverflow.com/a/20416230/827110

Answer (score 0):

try

`textView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(0,102, 51));` in inside your custom adapter textview

if you didn't use the custom adapter use `ArrayAdapter<Spanned>()` to make the custom color for the text.

Comment: I have not used custom adapter class.

Comment: change your arrayadapter to <Spanned> type to make the color.

Comment: Can you give example that how to use <Spanned> with Arrayadapter.

Answer (score 0):

this may help you...

```
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    // add your String items to array list
    ArrayList<Spanned> spannedList = new ArrayList<Spanned>(
            arrayList.size());
    for (int i = 0, N = arrayList.size(); i < N; i++) {
        String s = arrayList.get(i);
        String html = "<font color=\"#0000FF\">" + s + "</font>"; // blue color
        Spanned spanned = Html.fromHtml(html);
        spannedList.add(spanned);
    }
    ArrayAdapter<Spanned> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Spanned>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, spannedList);
```

you can set text to any color using color code. (here I used blue 0000FF). for more color codes see [here](http://html-color-codes.info/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Html.fromHtml()
```

Before using this you need to iterating the adapter value and store that value in one spanned variable like

```
Spanned out=Html.fromHtml("here you can use html tags like font color ,heading tag etc");
```